# toggle listchar settings

Tags: vimrc, set

I have a `listchars` setting in my .vimrc, which shows some characters, but not all. Sometimes I would like to see it differently. I could map two key combos to the two settings and change between them that way, but it would be better if I could toggle between the two with only one combo. How would that be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
let lc1='tab:»-,trail:·,nbsp:×,eol:$'
let lc2='tab:<->,trail:X,nbsp:_,eol:/'

function ChgListchars()
    if &listchars == g:lc1
        let &listchars = g:lc2
    else
        let &listchars = g:lc1
    endif
endfunction

nnoremap <F9> :call ChgListchars()<CR>
```

Comment: perfect, thank you!